# Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition Issues(Message:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request)

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i am facing below issue on windows 2008 r2 enterprise edition but it is fine on windows 2008 r2 standard edition.

**Problem:** .Net windows service called web services. Web services throwing below error..

**Error Message:**

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

at Errorlog.LogError(Exception objEx, Int32 userId, String pageURL)

at AuthorizationProcess.LoadProcess(DataSet dsProcessList)
```

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

**Stack Trace:**

```
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

at WebAuthorizationService.WSMediaAuthorizationService.AuthorizationProcess.LoadProcess(DataSet dsProcessList)

at WebAuthorizationService.Revision.LoadProcessForMediaServer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you are connecting to a sql server and the connection cannot be established.

Either you are pointing to a wrong sql server (a development machine perhaps?) or there is no physical connection between the two, the application server and the sql server.